# Parsing TFL json to HTML

Tags: html, json, api

total newbie I am trying to build a simple web page that will display local bus arrivals but not sure where to start with the processing of the data and out putting to a table

the API URL is https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/490004220V/Arrivals

Sample data

```
[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"-1261281243","operationType":1,"vehicleId":"YY64YKN","naptanId":"490004220V","stationName":"Hancock Road","lineId":"488","lineName":"488","platformName":"V","direction":"outbound","bearing":"182","destinationNaptanId":"","destinationName":"Dalston Junction","timestamp":"2020-03-01T20:13:39.3280692Z","timeToStation":1571,"currentLocation":"","towards":"Hackney Wick or Canary Wharf","expectedArrival":"2020-03-01T20:39:50Z","timeToLive":"2020-03-01T20:40:20Z","modeName":"bus","timing":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PredictionTiming, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","countdownServerAdjustment":"00:00:09.1238643","source":"2020-03-01T13:18:33.544Z","insert":"2020-03-01T20:14:11.716Z","read":"2020-03-01T20:14:21.259Z","sent":"2020-03-01T20:13:39Z","received":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"-728950935","operationType":1,"vehicleId":"YY64YKR","naptanId":"490004220V","stationName":"Hancock Road","lineId":"488","lineName":"488","platformName":"V","direction":"outbound","bearing":"182","destinationNaptanId":"","destinationName":"Dalston Junction","timestamp":"2020-03-01T20:13:39.3280692Z","timeToStation":361,"currentLocation":"","towards":"Hackney Wick or Canary Wharf","expectedArrival":"2020-03-01T20:19:40Z","timeToLive":"2020-03-01T20:20:10Z","modeName":"bus","timing":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PredictionTiming, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","countdownServerAdjustment":"00:00:09.5396016","source":"2020-03-01T13:18:33.544Z","insert":"2020-03-01T20:13:41.971Z","read":"2020-03-01T20:13:51.212Z","sent":"2020-03-01T20:13:39Z","received":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"-792585798","operationType":1,"vehicleId":"BJ11DVT","naptanId":"490004220V","stationName":"Hancock Road","lineId":"d8","lineName":"D8","platformName":"V","direction":"outbound","bearing":"182","destinationNaptanId":"","destinationName":"Crossharbour","timestamp":"2020-03-01T20:13:39.3280692Z","timeToStation":608,"currentLocation":"","towards":"Hackney Wick or Canary Wharf","expectedArrival":"2020-03-01T20:23:47Z","timeToLive":"2020-03-01T20:24:17Z","modeName":"bus","timing":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PredictionTiming, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","countdownServerAdjustment":"00:00:09.5404134","source":"2020-03-01T13:18:33.544Z","insert":"2020-03-01T20:13:11.678Z","read":"2020-03-01T20:13:21.166Z","sent":"2020-03-01T20:13:39Z","received":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"-1867782093","operationType":1,"vehicleId":"BJ11EBL","naptanId":"490004220V","stationName":"Hancock Road","lineId":"d8","lineName":"D8","platformName":"V","direction":"outbound","bearing":"182","destinationNaptanId":"","destinationName":"Crossharbour","timestamp":"2020-03-01T20:13:39.3280692Z","timeToStation":1785,"currentLocation":"","towards":"Hackney Wick or Canary Wharf","expectedArrival":"2020-03-01T20:43:24Z","timeToLive":"2020-03-01T20:43:54Z","modeName":"bus","timing":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PredictionTiming, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","countdownServerAdjustment":"00:00:09.5425500","source":"2020-03-01T13:18:33.544Z","insert":"2020-03-01T20:13:56.576Z","read":"2020-03-01T20:14:06.212Z","sent":"2020-03-01T20:13:39Z","received":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}}]
```

The output I am looking for is `lineName destinationName expectedArrival vehicleId`

Thanks in advance

Glen

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use fetch api and parse the result in an object. Then can call like following:

[Javascript Fetch Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Ok. I added appending table rows functionality. If you want to improve it take a look at [inserting table row on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Title</title>
</head>
<body>

 <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Route Number</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Arrival</th>
    <th>Vehicle ID</th>
  </tr>
   
</table> 

<script>
async function load() {
 let url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/490004220V/Arrivals';
 let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json(); 
 
 let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  
  obj.sort((a, b)=> { 
    a = new Date(a.expectedArrival);
    b =new Date(b.expectedArrival);
    return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0;
  });
  
 obj.forEach(o=>{
  let row = table.insertRow(-1); //
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = o.lineName;
  cell2.innerHTML = o.destinationName;
  cell3.innerHTML =o.expectedArrival
  cell4.innerHTML = o.vehicleId;
 });
}

load();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that part when I run the code on here it works but how would i get it to display on a web page

Comment: This is a big question :) did you create any project?

Comment: Ok. You can use my example in the html file Script section. But you need to Edit it. Because it wont produce a html table.

Comment: I have had to put what I have in an answer as its over 300 to long

Comment: two final bits of help how do i sort by o.expectedArrival and have the date formatted to plain 24 hour clock

Comment: I had sorted the response according to expectedArrival. take a look.